# Android M fingerprint Scanner Support example getting Nullpointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, keystore, secret-key

Application : FingerPrint Scanner Support

Source : GIT HUB : [Android FingerPrint Dialog](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog/)

Issue : Nullpointer exception

File Name : **MainAcitivty.java**

PATH:  https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/fingerprintdialog/MainActivity.java

Method :

```
   private boolean initCipher() {
        try {
            mKeyStore.load(null);
            SecretKey key = (SecretKey) mKeyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME, null);  
            mCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            return true;
        } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException
                | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
        }
    }
```

Getting `Nullpointer Exception` in this method.

Is it due to `keystore` or `Cipher` initialization ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the @Inject annotation has failed you so your mKeyStore is still null?  You could try pulling the initialization out of the FingerprintModule and into the onCreate of MainActivity.

Comment: How to run Application : FingerPrint Scanner Support

Source : GIT HUB : Android FingerPrint Dialog in both marshmallow and below versions it is being crashed if i run 4.4.2 version